# EPPlus: Exception when attempting to use SaveAs method: Can't load type System.Security.Crytopgraphy.Pkcs.SignedCms

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, epplus

I'm attempting to save a successfully loaded excel file as an .xlsm file and I'm getting the following error:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Error saving file C:\VS\ExcelManager\ExcelManager\File.xlsm ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms' from assembly 'System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at OfficeOpenXml.VBA.ExcelVbaSignature.GetSignature()
   at OfficeOpenXml.VBA.ExcelVbaSignature..ctor(ZipPackagePart vbaPart)
   at OfficeOpenXml.VBA.ExcelVbaProject.get_Signature()
   at OfficeOpenXml.VBA.ExcelVbaProject.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorkbook.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.SaveAs(FileInfo file)
   at ExcelManager.Controllers.ExcelController.PrepareExcelFile() in C:\VS\ExcelManager\ExcelManager\Controllers\ExcelController.cs:line 71
   at ExcelManager.Controllers.ExcelController.Get() in C:\VS\ExcelManager\ExcelManager\Controllers\ExcelController.cs:line 80
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext()}
```

}

Here's the code using EPPlus in .NET Core 2.0.:

```
{namespace ExcelManager.Controllers
{
[Route("api/excel")]
public class ExcelController : Controller
{

    //private const string XlsxContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12";
    private const string XlsxContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    private void PrepareExcelFile()
    {
        //https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/31
        //Otherwise, I get an EPP error
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance); 

        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo("File.xlsx"));
        pck.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
 //Add VBA Code here
        pck.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = sb.ToString();
        //Save as XLSM

        pck.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo("File.xlsm"));}
```

I also tried the EPPlus.CORE nuget package and received a "Not Supported Exception". I'm not trying to encrypt or do anything special with the file other than add VBA code and I have no problems opening and saving the file manually.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks some information, like what version of EPPlus are you using?

Anyway, I did the following:

Created a .Net Core 2.0 ASP.net core MVC project.
Installed EPPLus prerelease v4.5.0.1-beta (which supports .net core 2.0) and tried the following code:

```
 ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo("d:\\a.xlsx"));
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        //Add VBA Code here
        sb =new StringBuilder( "valid VB code");
        pck.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
        pck.Workbook.CodeModule.Code = sb.ToString();
        //Save as XLSM

        pck.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo("D:\\a.xlsm"));
```

And it works perfectly.

Please make sure that you are using the right EPPlus version.

Comment: I was using version 4.1.1, so I downloaded the version you did and that problem was resolved. I now have a different problem where it says I am opening a corrupted file. The only difference between my code and yours right now is that I am using a web api and returning a File via Get:

   `// GET api/excel
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            PrepareExcelFile(); //this does same thing as your code and works without error
            return File(@"file.xlsm", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");            
        }`

Comment: so, the file is generated successfully but it says that it is corrupted when you open it using Excel?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. After the SaveAs statement is run, when I open the file manually, it says the file is corrupt and then it attempts to repair the file and winds up removing the VBA code in the repair.

Comment: that is totally another issue that you need to ask for, I think you will find it already answered somewhere, from my experience, it is the VB code that you are inserting